# Filter applied to unexpected queries

Tags: wordpress

I am applying the `get_the_excerpt` and `get_the_content` filters to the search results for a custom post type.  The filters seem to be getting applied to additional queries in widgets, and not just the search query.  Is there a way to limit the filter to only apply to the search query.

I have tried to limit the filter so that it only applies under certain conditions, but it doesn't seem to honor the conditions:

## Adding the filters

```
add_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 'CourseStorm_Templates::coursestorm_alter_search_results_content' );
add_filter( 'get_the_content', 'CourseStorm_Templates::coursestorm_alter_search_results_content' );
```

## Filter code

```
// Get post taxonomies
$taxonomies = get_post_taxonomies();

// Alter post output for courses on the search page.
if ( in_array( 'my_custom_post_type', $taxonomies ) && is_search() && is_main_query()) :
    // do stuff to alter display of CPT
endif;
```

I have a query in a widget that this alteration is getting applied to when the widget is displayed on the search page.  I have confirmed that the widget query fails at least one of the conditionals (`is_search()`), so it shouldn't be applied.

## Widget query

```
$query_args = array(
    'post_type'   => 'my_custom_post_type',
    'tax_query'   => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'my_category',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => '0',
        )
    ),
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $query_args );

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
        $post_id = $the_query->post->ID;
        $meta = get_post_meta( $post_id );
        $title = get_the_title( $post_id );
        the_excerpt(); // the alterations from the filter are getting applied here.
    endwhile;

    wp_reset_query();
endif;
```

I expect the filter to apply only to the search results and not to the widget contents displayed on the search page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `remove_filter` [check docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_filter), function to remove the filter for the widget WP_Query. Depending on where your widget sidebar is located before or after main Posts Loop you can add a filter back after custom WP_Query. so your Widget query will look like this:

```
// remove filters before
remove_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 'CourseStorm_Templates::coursestorm_alter_search_results_content' );
remove_filter( 'get_the_content', 'CourseStorm_Templates::coursestorm_alter_search_results_content' );

$the_query = new WP_Query( $query_args );

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
        $post_id = $the_query->post->ID;
        $meta = get_post_meta( $post_id );
        $title = get_the_title( $post_id );
        the_excerpt();
    endwhile;

    wp_reset_query();
endif;

// add filters back
add_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 'CourseStorm_Templates::coursestorm_alter_search_results_content' );
add_filter( 'get_the_content', 'CourseStorm_Templates::coursestorm_alter_search_results_content' );
```

Comment: Thanks @Arthem, I had not thought of removing the filter before the widget query.  Doing so seems to have resolved my problem.